# round decimal to next number

Tags: c#

Can some one help me with the following problem, please?
I think its quite simple but i cant figure it out:

```
decimal _number  =  17 / 15;  // result is 1,1333333333
_number = Math.Round(_number, 1, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero); // result is 1,1
```

if variable _number has decimals , i want it to be rounded to the next number. In this case it would be: _number = 2.
thanks in advance

Comment: have a look at [`System.Math.Ceiling`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/1cz5da1c(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: your problem is `_number` is 1, not `1.33333` like you think.

Comment: `17 / 15` returns `1` no matter what type you assign it since it is an integer divison.

Comment: What do you want to round to if `_number` is negative? `Math.Ceiling(-2.5)` gives -2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to fix the integer division like this, because `17 / 15` is `1`:

```
decimal _number = 17M / 15M;
```

And after this just use:

```
int number = (int)Math.Ceiling(_number);
```

This leads to this:

```
0.0 => 0
0.1 => 1
1.1 => 2
1.7 => 2
2.1 => 3
```

If your two numbers are parameters from the type `int` just use `Decimal.Divide`:

```
decimal _number = Decimal.Divide(parameter1, parameter2);
```

Comment: Works, provided the original number actually *is* a decimal number, which in the OP's example isn't the case.

Answer (score 2):

You're performing an `integer` division here! The result is different from what you think:

```
decimal _number  =  17 / 15;
```

The result of this is `1`, not `1,133333`. You need to do this:

```
decimal _number = 17M / 15M;
```

You can then use the [`Math.Ceiling`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zx4t0t48%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method, which simply returns the next bigger integer to the given number:

```
decimal nextBiggerInt = Math.Ceiling(_number);
```

Comment: `Math.Round(_number + 0.5M)` will give you 3 if your original number is 2.0M.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Math.Ceiling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zx4t0t48%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method

```
decimal _number  =  17m / 15m;  // result is 1,1333333333
_number =  Math.Ceiling(_number);
```

Comment: @downvoter: please, add a comment explaining why you downvoted

Comment: have you tried your *solution*  - you don't even use `Math.Ceiling` and you still use `17 / 15`

Comment: added sufix to literals

Comment: now the integer part is ok but still you return `1m` instead of `2` ... you see - the downvote is not in vain

Comment: Why say to use `Math.Ceiling` while your code says `Math.Round`? Very confusing post.

Comment: it's nothing personal but simple things like this should be tested - it's really the simple act of using LINQpad, F#-interactive, whatever - but posting something and then editing a couple of times till its ok ... well

Comment: @Carsten, sorry for posting so fast. I didn't think I would fail on a so simple and trivial thing. I was wrong, I failed.